# How to do something firstly when the asp.net server start

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

I need an interface that can be run firstly when the application start.
We can write some code in Application_Start of global.ascx.
Is there any other method to finish it after some configurations in web.config,i don't wanna write any code in global.ascx
You know,we can implement the Interface 'IHttpModule' to　diy each request.
But the interface is not fix to application start.
which one is i wanna?
Thanks

Comment: That's `global.asax`. Why wouldn't use it? This is *exactly* what it does...

Comment: @Kobi, an http module has the advantage of being a reusable component, which can be easily added or removed in an application, just by using the `<httpModules>` section in web.config.

Comment: @Kobi, i wanna other who use my component cost less time configuration.It is better not to write in global.ascx .

Comment: It's `global.asax` - and for a reason!

Answer (score 1):

A `HttpModule` is something that *handles requests*, and is not directly related to the lifetime of an application. Even if it's reusable, it may not survive during the whole lifetime of an application. The `Global.asax` file, on the other hand, becomes a subclass of `HttpApplication`, which indeed is a class that *relates to the startup, shutdown and lifetime of a web application*. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2027ewzw.aspx), Global.asax is the file to put startup and shutdown code.

Comment: hey，in other word,who knows what load gobal.ascx that can be overloaded.

Comment: Normally, code that runs *when the HTTP Application starts* is placed in `global.asax`. There is no "overloading" involved - the application itself has just this one entry point, as it were.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Init](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpmodule.init.aspx) method of your module. It fires more or less around the same time  as the Application_Start for the Global.asax.

Comment: that init method will be run each time when meeting remote request.
But i only want to run one time.